# phpmyadmin throws a 404 on opening

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I have installed php5 and phpMyAdmin from the Ubuntu Software Centre on a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04.

when I enter localhost in my browser the following is displayed:

### **It works!**

*This is the default web page for this server.*

*The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.*

So something is working.

if I then type in `localhost/phpmyadmin` or `localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` the page returns a 404 error page, file not found.

I created a file in /var/www called test.php with one line in it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` when I try to access it through my browser, I get 403 Forbidden

This points to a permissions problem

with phpMyAdmin I also installed:

- Apache HTTP Server metapackage (apache2)
- Base support for JavaScript library packages (javascript-common)
- Fast webserver with minimal memory footprint (lighttpd)
- MySQL Client (mysql-client)
- GD module for php5 (php5-gd)
- MySQL Server (mysql-server)

When installing phpMyAdmin, I was not asked any questions, which I found interesting as on previous installs, I have been asked to choose a server.

The folder /etc/phpmyadmin has the following content:

- conf.d/
- config-db.php.ucf-dist

The folder conf.d has no content

Is there something I need to install which I haven't or is there something I can do to fix the 404 & 403 errors?

## Edit

owners in /var

```
:/var$ ls -lh
total 48K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4.0K Jun  9 12:16 backups
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root     4.0K Jun  9 13:28 cache
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4.0K Jun  9 16:01 crash
drwxr-xr-x 73 root root     4.0K Jun  8 19:24 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff    4.0K Apr 19 10:03 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        9 Jun  9 16:00 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4.0K Jun  9 16:01 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail     4.0K Apr 24 18:01 mail
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4.0K Apr 24 18:05 metrics
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4.0K Apr 24 18:01 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4 Jun  9 16:00 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4.0K Jun  8 19:41 spool
drwxrwxrwt  4 root root     4.0K Jun  9 16:25 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4.0K Jun  7 21:04 www
```

and:

```
...:/var$ ls -lh /var/www
total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  177 Jun  7 20:30 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 3.5K Jun  7 20:30 index.lighttpd.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   20 Jun  7 21:04 test.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    0 Jun  7 21:04 test.php~
```

on restarting the apache2 service I get the following in Terminal

```
simon@simon-VGN-AR71E:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
apache2: Syntax error on line 260 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

i renamed phpmyadmin.conf link and ran

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

see the broken link symbol in nautilus:

[image]

```
simon@simon-VGN-AR71E:~$ ls -lh /etc/apache2/conf.d
total 16K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  269 Jul 16  2012 charset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   45 Jun  7 21:14 javascript-common.conf -> /etc/javascript-common/javascript-common.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.3K Jul 16  2012 localized-error-pages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  143 Jul 16  2012 other-vhosts-access-log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun  9 17:28 phpmyadmin.conf -> ../../phpmyadmin/apache.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K Jul 16  2012 security
```

END===================================

Comment: I also face same type of problem and solved it changing the directory permission. But changing System folder's permission is not a good idea I think. You may create new server directory inside home.

Comment: Did you add this to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`? Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it is an apache permission problem. Try to put in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` the following lines

`<Directory />
AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

and check that the `/var/www` folders owner is `www-data`

==================================================================================

Install mysql server: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Here the installer will ask the mysql-server root password

Install apache 2: `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Test it: localhost (You must see "It works!" etc)

Install php5: `sudo apt-get install php5`

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Testing it: create the file php_info.php in /var/www/

The content of the file: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Install php modules: `sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-gd php5-xsl curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl`

Connect apache 2 and mysql together: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql`

Install phpmyadmin:

```
`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`
`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`
```

Connect php5 with mysql server:

Edit the file `/etc/php/apache2/php.ini`

Uncomment the following line: `extension=mysql.so`

Restart apache: `service apache2 restart`

Try phpmyadmin: `localhost/phpmyadmin/`

This worked for me many times.

Comment: Thanks for that,I changed the existing `AllowOverride none` with `AllowOverride All` no change, still 404. How do I find out the owner of a folder or file?

Comment: For example with `ls -lh`

Comment: `ls -lh` reports `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4.0K Jun  7 21:04 www`

Comment: Try to edit your `default` file in `sites-available` folder and put the bottom, after `</VirtualHost>` the following `Alias phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin`

Comment: I have added the details to the bottom of the question. chown makes all files in www www-data

Comment: `Alias phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` added, no change or do I need to restart the service?

Comment: Exactly :) `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: That's done and added the error I received to the bottom of the question. I'll try rebooting.

Comment: run, the following `sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`

Comment: I get `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf’: File exists`, still not working :(

Comment: Added the nautilus screenshot to bottom of the question.

Comment: Maybe the www-data user don't have a read permission to the link, can you paste me the result of: `sudo ln -lh /etc/apache2/conf.d`

Comment: `ln -lh` give `ln: invalid option -- 'l'`

Comment: Ohh, sorry, `sudo ls -lh /etc/apache2/conf.d`

Comment: Placed at the bottom of the question.

Comment: At the beginning you created a file test.php, that works or still throws 403?

Comment: You are welcome, try to remove phpmyadmin and install it from source.

Comment: I'll do that now. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I have downloaded phpMyAdmin-4.0.3-english.tar.gz but after searching for instructions on how to install it, I'm still looking at the screen , none the wiser. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have added a description to the bottom of my answer. Before you start the process remove all installed packages what you already installed (with apt-get remove `packagename`)

Comment: These are too many comments, and this discussion would be better suited for chat.

Comment: it's working for me by doing http://project.local/phpmyadmin after doing what exist in official ubuntu site by addin the including path to apache2/apache2.conf and the symolic links

Answer (score 50):

It seems to me that you forgot to tick `apache` during the phpmyadmin installation screen. You can check if that is the case by checking for the presence of `/etc/apache2/conf.d
/phpmyadmin` file.

You can reconfigure phpmyadmin with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

You will see the following screen:

[image: Choose Web Server]

Tick apache (using spacebar), and tab to OK.

Comment: I get `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf’: File exists` after I complete this. It still doesn't work!

Comment: Try restarting apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`)

Comment: I tried that, see the edit at the bottom of the original question

Comment: At this point, I'd probably download phpmyadmin and unzip it in `/var/www/`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot to **tick** the apache2 while installation with tasksel.

Comment: You're golden. Why is this not ticked by default and why does it let you proceed without making a choice?

Comment: During initial installation, I kind of pressed <ENTER> instead of <SPACE> to select Apache2, and the window disappeared.

Comment: AAHAAA!!! I was about to remove and reinstall phpmyadmin. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 20):

I know this is a very old problem, so if you encounter such an error and the above does not help you, this might:

Use this command `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to open the file using `nano` then add the following line:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Save and close. Then restart the server. This should work.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Really, its worked for me

Comment: Thats the solution for me!

Comment: Also worked for me!

Comment: Nice this worked for me, can anyone explain what exactly happened here?

Comment: This is because you skipped some steps while installing phpmyadmin. When you were supposed to apply apache2, you supposed to select using spacebar, press tab to move the cursor to ok, then press enter. If you didn't do this, this is short code to link phpmyadmin with apache2.

Comment: worked for me, on windows 11 wsl2 ubuntu apache2. And I did select using spacebar tab etc as suggested by @AntonyMN, at least it looked like I did on screen...

Comment: Thanks, this works for me too:)

Answer (score 0):

This can be pretty obvious but, does /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf exists?. If it does, try letting dpkg do all the job. rm the link you manually created and run again:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 0):

My phpmyadmin was not opening.

The problem was, because I tried to call it with https instead of http.