# apache is not starting after I upgraded to 13.10

Tags: apache2

Yesterday I upgraded to 13.10, but aphache server fails to restart. When I enter `sudo service apache2 restart`
I get following error :

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 265 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.21/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.21/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: can you have a look at this, ---- http://askubuntu.com/questions/368515/upgraded-to-ubuntu-13-10-apache-not-able-to-start

Comment: @Tasos 
It doesn't work.

Comment: Try to reinstall your `apache2` package by running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it at last but it was not that easy. I had to purge and reinstall; apache2, php5, phpmyadmin, but I didn't touch mysql because I was afraid of losing my databases. Phpmyadmin gave me 404 error, I had to change folder permissions like

```
 sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www
 sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/
```

These links are helpful :

[phpmyadmin throws a 404 on opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306094/phpmyadmin-throws-a-404-on-opening?rq=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905825/resolve-error-default-site-does-not-exist-after-update-to-ubuntu-13-10-and-apach

[Cannot find /etc/apache2/sites-available/default when configuring Apache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386382/cannot-find-etc-apache2-sites-available-default-when-configuring-apache)

EDIT :[image]

here I opted for No, because it might delete database config in phpmyadmin, luckily all database appeared in phpmyadmin after reinstallation.